# Difference between two sentence

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between the two sentences below?:

They have arrived back home.
They have arrived home.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Including adverbial ***back*** in a context like *They have arrived [**back**] **in/at** London* would unambiguously imply that they have ***returned*** to London (i.e. - that's where they were until some point in the past when they ***left*** London). Without ***back***, it's possible they've just arrived in London for the first time in their lives, never having been there before. But ***by definition*** they must have been at "home" in the past, so including ***back*** or not doesn't really change anything except to slightly emphasise the sense of "returning".

Answer (score 0):

The two commenters have given you some pretty good information. The key is that "back home" often means "back to one's hometown/home country/etc", whereas just "home" typically (but not exclusively) refers to the house/apartment you currently live in.

For example, I'm not from the country where I currently live, so people at work sometimes ask me:

> "How often do you go **back home**?"

In this context, that means "How often do you go **back to your home country**?". It would be awkward if they asked me "How often do you go **home**?" - it would almost imply that I sleep at work rather than go back to my house/apartment at night.

Here's another example:

> "Are you out partying? No, I'm **home**."

This simply means you're in your house or apartment, rather than out at a bar or a club.

So if, for example, I have some friends from out of town who were visiting me over the weekend, and now they're letting me know their flight back to their hometown has just landed, I might say "they've arrived back home". If, instead, my parents drove back to their house after coming over for dinner, and my mom is texting me that they just parked the car in the garage, I might say "they've arrived home".

Does that help illustrate the difference?

Comment: The comment by FumbleFingers doesn't say what you do, although it doesn't preclude that interpretation. It's saying what also might be very possible (in my opinion as a non-native speaker of English), especially in a context I'll assume here, and that is where the person merely left home recently: *I woke up, remembered John's birthday, went to the store to buy him a present, and then as I arrived back home...* – while you do make a brief implication of this sort of thing, the focus is on one's home country/town (the idiomatic meaning), and I don't believe that ought to be the case at all.